# Java AssertEquals on two strings using regex

Tags: regex, junit

I have two strings:

```
String actual   = "abcd1234efgh";
String expected = "abcd5678efgh";
```

The number part will always be different.
How can I make `assertEquals` return `true` to these strings the most efficient way possible?

Comment: `actual = expected;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Assert.assertTrue(actual.matches("abcdf\\d+efgh"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
assertEquals(expected.replaceAll("\\D+", ""), actual.replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
```

`.replaceAll("\\D+", "")` will remove all non-digits from both string objects.